# Visual C++ declaring a string array

Tags: visual-c++

I am working in Visual C++. I'm giving following command

```
String nodename[100];
```

but this command is giving the following error

> "error : 'System::String' : a native
>   array cannot contain this managed
>   type"

So what should I do now ?

Comment: If you don't know what native arrays and managed types are, you should probably not bother with managed C++ at all and use C# instead :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write a native C++ application, then you can't, as the error says, use managed types.

That means you have to use the C++ string class,

```
#include <string> // at the top of the file
std::string nodename[100]; // where you want to declare the array
```

instead of `System::String`.

On the other hand, if you want to make a managed C++/CLI application, then you can't use native arrays. (But can use all the .NET types)

Comment: the above command gives the following error
'std' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: Then you didn't add the `#include` part properly. Put that at the very top of the file.

Comment: and it is string, not string.h

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say whether you want Managed C++, C++/CLI, or unmanaged C++

managed C++

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/csarrays01.aspx

C++/CLI

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliarrays.aspx

unmanaged C++ (standard C++)

std::string nodename[100]; // uses STL string, not .NET String

Comment: i want to use unmanaged C++ 
std::string nodename[100];
this command give following error even though i use #include"string.h" also
'std' : is not a class or namespace name

Answer (score 0):

OK. First off it looks like you are using *managed* C++ (ick). Secondly, you are trying to declare an array of strings (not chars, but entire strings). Is that really what you want to do? Are you sure you don't want something like `char nodename[100]` or just `String nodename`?

If you really want an array of strings, it looks like the compiler either wants you to use one of its managed vector-like types to do it, or to use only unmanaged types to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name[5] = {"Marco","Jenna","Alex","Dina","Allyson"};
    int index = 5;

    printf("List:\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        cout << name[i] << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.