# visual c++ copy textbox content

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

how to copy textbox->Text content in a char array? 
i m working in vc++.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise, what is the type of Text for example? otherwise we won't be able to address your issue. By the way if you are using C++ why on earth would you like to mess around with char arrays: prefer std::string!

Comment: If you are genuinely a new user, I apologize, but I can't help noticing a certain similarity to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504905/0visual-c-declaration-of-string-type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505026, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499815/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499603/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504905/
If that is you, you'll get much better answers by **improving the question**, rather than asking the same thing again under a different username.

Comment: None of these questions have provided enough information for a proper answer, and neither does this one. If you want an answer, tell us what we need to know, instead of endlessly repeating your question.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What type is textbox? What type is Text? Why does it have to be stored in a char array, rather than a proper C++ string? What is the problem you're trying to solve? What does your actual code look like? Give us some information

Answer (score 1):

Use CWnd::GetWindowText()

```
CString str;
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_WHATEVER);
pWnd->GetWindowText(str);
```

Puts the contents of the control into the CString or you can use the array version:

```
TCHAR sz[10];
int nRet = pWnd->GetWindowText(sz, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is unclear, so I'll have to assume things.

Assuming you are using MFC, add a control type variable to your edit box (say m_Edit), and use m_Edit.GetWindowText() to get the text.

Or if you're using plain Win32, use the [GetWindowText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API.

On an additional note, like another user pointed out, stop using things like fixed-size character arrays to store strings if you are using c++. Use something like std::string or use CString if you're using MFC. By doing so, you can manipulate strings much easily and your code will be less error prone.

Cheers, Rajesh. MVP, Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.....

```
CString csTbxName;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1,csTbxName);
const char* pchTbxName = csTbxName.GetBuffer();
char chTbxNameDup[5000];
ZeroMemory(chTbxNameDup,5000);
if(csTbxName.GetLength() < 5000)
{
    memcpy(chTbxNameDup,(void*)pchTbxName,csTbxName.GetLength());
}
```